# While fetching all links,Ignore logout link from the loop and continue navigation in selenium java

Tags: java, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am fetching all the links in the page and navigating to all links.
In that one of the link is Logout.
How do i skip/ignore Logout link from the loop?

I want to skip Logout link and proceed

List demovar=driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
       System.out.println(demovar.size());

```
   ArrayList<String> hrefs = new ArrayList<String>(); //List for storing all href values for 'a' tag

      for (WebElement var : demovar) {
          System.out.println(var.getText()); // used to get text present between the anchor tags
          System.out.println(var.getAttribute("href"));
          hrefs.add(var.getAttribute("href")); 
          System.out.println("*************************************");
      }

      int logoutlinkIndex = 0;

      for (WebElement linkElement : demovar) {
               if (linkElement.getText().equals("Log Out")) {
                           logoutlinkIndex = demovar.indexOf(linkElement);
                           break;
                }

      }

      demovar.remove(logoutlinkIndex);

      //Navigating to each link
      int i=0;
      for (String href : hrefs) {
          driver.navigate().to(href);
          System.out.println((++i)+": navigated to URL with href: "+href);
          Thread.sleep(5000); // To check if the navigation is happening properly.
          System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
```

Comment: Are you sure the link element text is "Log Out"?
Also, consider using `for(int i = 0; i < <condition>; i++) { ...` for your second and third loops, I think that's more of what you're looking for since you're referencing the index in both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to leave out the **Logout** link from the loop instead of creating the *List* as `driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));` as an alternative you can use:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[not(contains(.,'Log Out'))]"));
```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Protractor Conditional Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62043616/protractor-conditional-selector/62043910#62043910)
- [How to locate the button element using Selenium through Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59796113/how-to-locate-the-button-element-using-selenium-through-python/59796217#59796217)
- [What does contains(., 'some text') refers to within xpath used in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57976490/what-does-contains-some-text-refers-to-within-xpath-used-in-selenium/57976746#57976746)
- [How does dot(.) in xpath to take multiple form in identifying an element and matching a text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58114813/how-does-dot-in-xpath-to-take-multiple-form-in-identifying-an-element-and-mat/58117536#58117536)

Answer (score 1):

1. Java approach to remove "not interesting" link using [Stream.filter()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) function:

   ```
   List<String> hrefs = driver.findElements(By.className("a"))
           .stream()
           .filter(link -> link.getText().equals("Log out"))
           .map(link -> link.getAttribute("href"))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```
2. [Using XPath `!=` operator](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) solution to collect only links which text is not equal to `Log Out`:

   ```
   List<String> hrefs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[text() != 'Log out']"))
           .stream()
           .map(link -> link.getAttribute("href"))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```