# What does contains(., 'some text') refers to within xpath used in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, xpath-1.0

I am new to selenium coding, and I am seeing several xpaths that contain (.,'followed by something')  what does the ., refer to?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the question to include one or more sample xpath examples that show this. By seeing the full context it will be possible to verify that the `.` refers to the current element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **`.`** character within the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) is the short form of `text()`

As an example if an WebElement is represented within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) as:

```
<span>Use this payment method</span>
```

Effective [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) will be:

- *xpath 1*:

  ```
  //span[text()='Use this payment method']
  ```
- *xpath 2*:

  ```
  //span[contains(., 'Use this payment method')]
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to locate the button element using Selenium through Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59796113/how-to-locate-the-button-element-using-selenium-through-python/59796217#59796217)
- [While fetching all links,Ignore logout link from the loop and continue navigation in selenium java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57293901/while-fetching-all-links-ignore-logout-link-from-the-loop-and-continue-navigatio/57294355#57294355)
- [How does dot(.) in xpath to take multiple form in identifying an element and matching a text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58114813/how-does-dot-in-xpath-to-take-multiple-form-in-identifying-an-element-and-mat/58117536#58117536)