# Can We create a Xpath with multiple contain() Function and a xpath axes

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, parent-child, contains, axis

For a  curiosity I  tried to create an xpath of orangehrm website leave  portal and I  have tried to  make an xpath with 2 contains and xpath  axes

```
//*[contains(@class,'oxd-main-menu-item active') and 
   (contains(@class,'oxd-main-menu-item-wrapper')/child::a) ]
```

- `contains(@class,'oxd-main-menu-item active')` : link  to  click
- `contains(@class,'oxd-main-menu-item-wrapper')/child::a)` : parent of link  access through  the xpath  axes

I am  aware that  this method is  possible

```
//div[contains(@class, 'measure-tab') and contains(., 'someText')]
```

but  my  question is, is it  possible can we also add xpath axes with one of the contains function?

[image]

All the things I have tried I have added in Description

Comment: Can you elaborate, what element are you trying to get?

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: _leave portal_: which element?

Comment: You haven't actually said what you are trying to achieve; it's difficult to infer your requirements from code that is clearly wrong. The reason your code doesn't work is that contains() returns a boolean and booleans don't have children.

Answer (score 0):

In short and crisp, yes you create [*xpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447) with multiple [contains()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59796217/7429447) function as follows:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'measure-tab') and contains(., 'someText')]
```

---

### This usecase

Given the HTML:

```
<li class="oxd-main-menu-item-wrapper" data-v-6475d26d="" data-v-636d6b87="">
    <a class="oxd-main-menu-item active" href="/web/index.php/leave/viewLeaveModule" data-v-6475d26d="">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 500 500" role="presentation" class="oxd-icon oxd-main-menu-item--icon" data-v-bddebfba="" data-v-6475d26d="">
            <g fill="currentColor">
                <path ...></path>
            </g>
        </svg>
        <span class="oxd-text oxd-text--span oxd-main-menu-item--name" data-v-7b563373="" data-v-6475d26d="">Leave</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

The desired `<a>` element:

```
<a class="oxd-main-menu-item active" href="/web/index.php/leave/viewLeaveModule" data-v-6475d26d="">
```

is within it's parent `<li>` element:

```
<li class="oxd-main-menu-item-wrapper" data-v-6475d26d="" data-v-636d6b87="">
```

To identify the element you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  li.oxd-main-menu-item-wrapper > a.oxd-main-menu-item.active
  ```
- Using *cssSelector* and *contains* clause:

  ```
  li[class*='oxd-main-menu-item-wrapper'] > a[class*='oxd-main-menu-item']
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  //li[@class='oxd-main-menu-item-wrapper']/a[@class='oxd-main-menu-item active']
  ```
- Using *xpath* and [*contains()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57976746/7429447):

  ```
  //li[contains(@class, 'oxd-main-menu-item-wrapper')]/a[contains(@class, 'oxd-main-menu-item active')]
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is whether you can apply an XPath to the `contains()` function, the answer is no. That function returns a boolean and you can't XPath off that.

However, you can achieve what (I think) you want.

Instead of `(contains(@class,'oxd-main-menu-item-wrapper')/child::a)` you can instead use:

```
//*[contains(@class,'oxd-main-menu-item active') and 
    contains(@class,'oxd-main-menu-item-wrapper') and 
    child::a ]
```

to test whether the matched element has a class that contains those two values and has a child `a` element.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean by "you can't XPath off a boolean", but it's very informal terminology: the rule in the spec is that for an axis expression, the context item must be a node.