# How does dot(.) in xpath to take multiple form in identifying an element and matching a text

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, xpath-1.0

I have the below dom structure:

```
<h3 class="popover-title">
 <div class="popup-title">
   <div class="title-txt">Associated Elements&nbsp;&nbsp(5)</div>
 </div>
</h3>
```

I am trying to write an xpath which will identify the title "Associated Elements" under h3 tag.

When my xpath is

```
//div[contains(@class, popover)]//h3[contains(.,'Associated Elements')]
```

the element is identified.

However when my xpath is

```
//div[contains(@class, popover)]//h3[contains(text(),'Associated Elements')]
```

the element is not identified.
As per my understanding the dot(.) is a replacement for text(), but then why does it not identify the element when I use the text() function.

However, for another dom structure:

```
<h3 class="popover-title">
   <a class="btn-popover" href="#">x</a>
   "Associated Elements"
</h3>
```

The xpath :

```
//div[contains(@class, popover)]//h3[contains(text(),'Associated Elements')]
```

&

```
//div[contains(@class, popover)]//h3[contains(.,'Associated Elements')]
```

works fine.

Can someone please explain the behaviour of dot(.) under both these scenarios?

Is there a better way to write an xpath that holds good for both the exmaples? Please suggest.

Comment: Both of the `xpath` shouldn't match the first html block. You need to replace `//div` with `//h3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) is tagged so this answer would be based on [xpath-1.0](/questions/tagged/xpath-1.0) and the associated [XML Path Language (XPath) Version 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/) specifications.

---

### contains(string, string)

The function [`boolean contains(string, string)`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-contains) returns true if the first argument string contains the second argument string, and otherwise returns false. As an example:

```
//h3[contains(.,'Associated Elements')]
```

---

### Text Nodes

Character data is grouped into [text nodes](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-Text-Nodes). As much character data as possible is grouped into each text node. The *string-value* of a text node is the character data. A text node always has at least one character of data. In the below example, `text()` selects all text node children of the context node:

```
//h3[text()='Associated Elements']
```

In your usecase, within the HTML the text **Associated Elements &nbsp(5)** have **`&nbsp;`** which is alternatively referred to as a **fixed space** or **hard space**, **NBSP (non-breaking space)** used in programming to create a space in a line that cannot be broken by word wrap. Within HTML, **`&nbsp;`** allows you to create multiple spaces that are visible on a web page and not only in the source code.

---

### Analyzing your code trials

Your first code trial with:

```
//h3[contains(.,'Associated Elements')]
```

locates the element as it successfully identifies with partial text *Associated Elements*

Your second code trial with:

```
//h3[contains(text(),'Associated Elements')]
```

**fails** as the element contains some more characters e.g. `&nbsp;` in addition to the text *Associated Elements*.

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to locate the button element using Selenium through Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59796113/how-to-locate-the-button-element-using-selenium-through-python/59796217#59796217)
- [What does contains(., 'some text') refers to within xpath used in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57976490/what-does-contains-some-text-refers-to-within-xpath-used-in-selenium/57976746#57976746)
- [While fetching all links,Ignore logout link from the loop and continue navigation in selenium java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57293901/while-fetching-all-links-ignore-logout-link-from-the-loop-and-continue-navigatio/57294355#57294355)

Comment: ``fails the element contains some more characters in addition to the text Associated Elements`` don't you mean ``fails the element contains some more elements in addition to the text Associated Elements`` ?

Comment: Thanks @MosheSlavin Updated the verbatim for more brevity.

Answer (score 0):

The `text()` in `contains(text(),'Associated Elements')` is a selector that matches all of the text nodes that are children of the context node - it returns a node-set. That node-set is converted to string and passed to the `contains()` function.

`text()` isn't a function but a node test. It is used to select all text-node children of the context node. So, if the context node is an element named x, then text() selects all text-node children of x.

When you use `contains(., 'Associated Elements')` only an individual text node is passed to the function and it is able to uniquely match the text.

**Note:** copied and edited from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655549/xpath-containstext-some-string-doesnt-work-when-used-with-node-with-more) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493732/difference-between-text-and-string).