# How to select nodes using find_elemets_by_xpath() with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-1.0

I use find_elements_by_xpath to know if keywords exists

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "' + str(key) + '")]')
```

when keyword = 0.5 HR which returns 0.5 HR (correctly)

when keyword = 5 HR which still returns both 5 HR and  0.5 HR (wrong, 0.5 HR is not 5 HR)

Is it possible to avoid?

Answer (score 0):

I'm imagine you have following code snippet:

```
<div>
    <div>0.5 HR</div>
    <div>5 HR</div>
</div>
```

If you query with `contains` function with value `5 HR` like this:

```
//*[contains(text(), "5 HR")]
```

Sure it will return 2, because there are indeed 2 elements that contain `5 HR` text.

May you want query with exact value, so you can't use `contains` function.

Use equal **`=`** :

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[text()="' + str(key) + '"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with, using `contains(text(), "sometext")` may make the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) expression a bit flaky. I would have used either *text()* or *contains(string, string)*

---

### text()

[`text()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-Text-Nodes) considers/selects all text node children of the context node

---

### contains()

[`contains()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-contains) function returns true if the first argument string contains the second argument string, and otherwise returns false.

---

### An example

Consider the example below:

- HTML:

  ```
  <ul>
      <li>0.5 HR</li>
      <li>5 HR</li>
  </ul>
  ```
- To select only the node with text as **0.5 HR** you need to use:

  ```
  //key = 0.5 HR
  driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[text()='" + str(key) + "']")
  ```
- To select only the node with text as **5 HR** you need to use:

  ```
  //key = 5 HR
  driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[text()='" + str(key) + "']")
  ```
- To select both the nodes with text as **0.5 HR** and **5 HR** you need to use:

  ```
  //key = 5 HR
  driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[contains(., '" + str(key) + "')]")
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion in:

- [How does dot(.) in xpath to take multiple form in identifying an element and matching a text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58114813/how-does-dot-in-xpath-to-take-multiple-form-in-identifying-an-element-and-mat/58117536#58117536)