# How to locate the button element using Selenium through Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find the element and click for the button "Not Now". I've tried with with css_selector, xpath, but I"m unable at all to find the proper way.

HTML:

[image]

Comment: Please do not share code/data as an image. Can you share your attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To locate and `click()` on the element with text as **Not Now** you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Not Now']").click()
  ```

---

However, the element looks dynamic to me so you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following *Locator Strategy*:

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div//button[text()='Not Now']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [What does contains(., 'some text') refers to within xpath used in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57976490/what-does-contains-some-text-refers-to-within-xpath-used-in-selenium/57976746#57976746)
- [While fetching all links,Ignore logout link from the loop and continue navigation in selenium java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57293901/while-fetching-all-links-ignore-logout-link-from-the-loop-and-continue-navigatio/57294355#57294355)
- [How does dot(.) in xpath to take multiple form in identifying an element and matching a text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58114813/how-does-dot-in-xpath-to-take-multiple-form-in-identifying-an-element-and-mat/58117536#58117536)

Comment: You were right, it worked with the 2nd method. Do you have any documentation for this kind of scenarios or a place where I can learn more about? Thank you a lot!